# wyswig editor issue in magento 2 enterprise edition

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

### Added below code into Ui component layout file but In enterprice version it is showing default page builder functionality not showing wyswig editor

```
<field name="content">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Content</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">post</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">content</item>
            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-wide</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Answer (score 2):

Page Builder is enabled for all WYSIWYG fields unless explicitly disabled. You can disable it per instance using the following code:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

You can read more about this in our developer docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/reference/architecture.html#integration-with-magento-and-custom-modules

Comment: Nice!! very useful. it fulfilled my requirement. You save my day Thanks Dave!

Comment: No problem @ChandraPrakashGupta, glad it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You miss formElement attribute in field tag,take this as reference https://github.com/magento-devdocs/pagebuilder-examples/blob/master/Example/PageBuilderQuote/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_example_quote_form.xml